# SP2013: Customizing Blog template with CSR

Tags: blog, client-side-rendering

I'm trying to customize blog site, I've found examples hot to customize templates with CSR, but that doesn't work with blog.

Here is the example of code I used:

```
    function registerBlogsRenderer()
{
    var blogContext = {};
    blogContext.Templates = {};
    blogContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Body": {
            "View": func1
        },
        "Title": {
            "View": func1      
        },
        "Author": {
            "View": func1      
        }       
    };
    blogContext.Templates.Footer = func1;


    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(blogContext);
}
```

Everything works fine with the fields, but nothing happens to Footer and Header.

I use **Summary view** for my blog with **Boxed view style**

Please give me any hint how can I catch different parts of blog post element, such as header, footer or any others. What are their names to apply to them. Post few strings of example code if possible, please.

I know I can use **OnPostRender** but I hoped I could customize post elements partially, not the whole HTML block at once.

Comment: I beg my pardons, i trimmed all the code to make my question more simplier for readers. This is what my func1 does:   `code`   function func1(ctx) {
        return "<b>FUNC1</b>"
    }
`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *func1* probably throws an error when it tries to access a property of *ctx* like *ctx.currentItem*. That's an assumption based on the fact you use *func1* for fields as well as for the footer. In that case you should be able to see a text similar to *"TypeError: ctx.CurrentItem is null"* in the footer of your list.

Maybe we can help you better when you show us what *func1* is actually doing.

### UPDATE:

I modified your code and tested it successfully on a blog site.
Please try this code:

```
(function(){
    var blogContext = {};
    blogContext.Templates = {};
    blogContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Body": {
            "View": func1
        },
        "Title": {
            "View": func1      
        },
        "Author": {
            "View": func1      
        }       
    };
    blogContext.Templates.Footer = func1;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(blogContext);
})()

function func1(ctx) { 
    return "<b>FUNC1</b>" 
}
```

BTW: Setting the view style to boxed will have no effect when you use custom CSR.

### Update 2:

Summary View is a server-rendered view and CSR will not be applied to it

Comment: I would not go so far as to say `Header` and `Footer` *usually* only take a string.  They are just as capable of being assigned a function as any other property of `Templates`.

Comment: I removed that statement.

Comment: @DanielStölzner, thank you for the answer. I added comment to show what func1 does. I see console in both Chrome and IE, there were no errors related to possible exceptions, throwned by my code. I just see that frontpage of blog shows post with some stuff at the bottom and i would like to have access to all parts of the template it uses. The code i have allows me only operate with fileds templates related to post items. In most views these parts are called like Header and Footer but blog seems to be smth outstanding)))

Comment: @AlexanderLarin Please see my updated answer for working code.

Comment: @DylanCristy thanks for ur help too, sorry, i confused ur nicknames first)

Comment: @DanielStölzner Thank you for the suggestion, i changed my code in accordnance with ur recomendations. I additionally created 3 more functions (func2, func3, func4), each of them returns "func2", "func3", "func4" - just to not confuse which template fires which function. When i use "all records" view for posts, i see "func4" string at the bottom, which corresponds for footer. When i go to Summary view, there is no "func4" there.

Comment: I just want to understnd - if there is a proper name for footer template for this view or i only have to work with html in OnPostRender handler? Cos i want to use Summary view and Boxed view style. At this moment i dont understand is there any special difference between other regular view and summary view, is there any reason why standart approaches dont work for summary view.

Comment: Summary View is a server-rendered view and CSR will not be applied to it.

Comment: @DanielStölzner please add ur last comment to ur answer so i will be able to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Done. And sorry for figuring it out so late. Even though you wrote in bold that it's a Summary View I thought it wouldn't matter until it occurred to me that it actually matters.